# How to move controls from one tab to another in C# winform program?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabpage

I have a C# winform program that has many tabs, and I want to move controls between tabs. and code as below:

```
private void OnTabControlTabSelected(object sender , EventArgs e)
{
    TabPage page = (sender as TabControl).SelectedTab;
    foreach(Control control in mLastSelectedTab.Controls)
    {
        this.mLastSelectedTab.Controls.Remove(control);
        page.Controls.Add(control);
    }
}
```

I remove the control from the last selected tab and add it to the new selected tab, but the result is that some controls are added successfully, some are not, I set a breakpoint in this code, and found that the foreach loop doesn't loop through every control in the last selected tab. please help me to solve this problem, thank you!

Comment: What is the purpose of doing so? It would be wise to have duplicate controls is the next tab.

Comment: The purpose is avoid duplicate, The program has many tabs(more than 30, or 40) and each tab has the same controls, If I duplicate each control, the time for opening tabs will be very long.

Comment: The Controls collection is an ArrangedElementCollection. The collection changes when you call Remove: "When a Control is removed from the control collection, all subsequent controls are moved up one position in the collection." (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.remove%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Your for each loop is trying to iterate through a collection that keeps changing.

Comment: How to loop through each control after I removed control?

Comment: You must loop backwards, for (int ix = mLastSelectedTab.Count - 1; ix >= 0; ix--) mLastSelectedTab.Controls[ix].Parent = page;  Do keep in mind that when you do this, the use of a TabPage starts to get pretty pointless.  Just resize the TabControl so only the tab strip is still visible.